# Java ASTParser: How to find global variable (data-fields) from a class

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using ASTParser to find variable declarations but it does not distinguish between global variables (data-fields for classes) and the rest of variables. Can anyone help me with this task?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to [setResolveBindings](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTParser.html) before parsing.

Then you can inquire about information on symbols by invoking [getAnnotations](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTParser.html).

A worked example can be found [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/how-to-resolve-bindings-when-using-eclipse-jdt-astparser/).

Answer (score 0):

You will need the parser to visit [VariableDeclarationFragment](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FMethodDeclaration.html). The [VariableDeclarationStatement](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FVariableDeclarationStatement.html) in the example Ira linked to only works for local variable declarations.

Change it like so to get all of the variables:

```
public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment fragment) {
    IVariableBinding binding = fragment.resolveBinding();

    System.out.println("binding variable declaration type: " +binding.getVariableDeclaration().getType().toString());
    System.out.println("binding Name: " +binding.getName());

    return true;
}
```